# Changing values with grep or sed

Tags: regex, sed, grep

Can I increase some numbers in txt files with grep/sed?

I want to find all numbers in file and increase them for 5. Is that possible with grep and sed or I need to write app for that?

EDIT:
File has n lines which begin with number - number and than some text.
Like title for movie.

example line:

```
34 - 36 : Some text.
```

Comment: You'll want to use sed or perl for this, not grep. What have you tried?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the format of your files?

Comment: `grep` is designed to select, not edit, data.  It is the wrong tool for the job.  I hesitate to say it can't be done in `sed`, but you'd need some sort of extended regular expression support to do the addition.  You might be able to do it with `awk`.  I'd probably use Perl if faced with the problem; Python would likely do just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably awk.  Change the record separator to whitespace (assuming this is what you want to do), then if a record matches the regex `^[0-9]*$` convert to number add 5 and print, otherwise print.

This is a pretty complete solution but "left as exercise" to code up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl as:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d+)/$1+5/eg' filename
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/ov6MU2)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use `awk` [Changing the Contents of a Field](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields)

```
>cat 1.txt
34 - 36 : Some text.


cat 1.txt | awk '{ $1=$1+5; $3=$3+5; print $0; }'
39 - 41 : Some text.
```

Comment: That works if the fields are always fields 1 and 3.  It is not clear from the question that the text file is formatted sufficiently rigidly.

Comment: You are right. Anyway if Steva changes his question and says that any field can be a number I will change my answer.

Comment: +1 for the concept. Can be tightened a bit with the `+=` operator, and the useless use of cat.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+/$((&+5))/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e'  file
```